# python for .net issue with windows8 (probably)

Tags: python, .net, windows-8, clr, python.net

I am succesfully using python for .net to connect with VB code (namely compiled .dll's)
However recently my client using windows8 reported strange issue that we located at `import clr`
This is what I call:

```
import os,sys, site
site.addsitedir(clr_path)
import clr
```

And the clr is:

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'clr.pyd')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

And it's all working fine at numerous windows7 machines, but in win8 I get this:

[image: error msg]

It seems like not all libraries are imported and it fails at dictionaries (which I avoid anyway and stick to basic datatypes :) )

Do you have any clue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: see here: http://grokbase.com/t/python/pythondotnet/13b689d6f9/python-net-python-net-on-windows-8-1
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2013-November/001434.html